# Share facebook session token from client to server

Tags: c#, android, ios, facebook, asp.net-mvc-5

I've successfully implemented `Facebook SDK 3.0` in my `Android` project for senior project. Also my android project uses `4.4.2.`

But I haven't used `Facebook API` before. So I want to know if there is a way for a `session token` created in an `Android or ios client` to be sent and used in a `asp.net web server`.

Also how am I suppose to handle the expired session tokens on the server side? Is there a way to have a session token that does not expire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the expired sessions, you can follow this link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

And, NO, there is no way to have a session token that does not expire.